# Executing a code when thread gets Blocked by Intrinsic Lock

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronize

Is there any way to run a piece of code when a thread accesses a locked object ?

```
public class Student implements Runnable {

private String name;
private Workshop w;

public Student(String name,Workshop workshop) {
    this.name = name;
    this.w=workshop;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    this.w.getReady();
    this.w.file(this.name);
    this.w.cut(this.name);
    this.w.punch(this.name); //Synchronized Method

    if(Thread.currentThread().getState()==Thread.State.BLOCKED)
        System.out.println(this.name+" is waiting in queue");

    System.out.println(this.name+" has finished and is going home");
}

}
```

This is a simulation for a Workshop scenario where each and every student has to file,cut and punch the metal workpiece.
Since punching is turn by turn, I have declared it as synchronized, as every student (thread) will have to wait for their turn to punch.
All I want to know is,if there some in-built method or a way to write a method that gets executed when a thread gets blocked and is waiting for the intrinsic lock to be unlocked.


**Example**

```
public void onBlock() {
    System.out.println(this.name+" is waiting in queue");
    ...
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, no -- if your thread is waiting on something, it can't go off and execute something else (without some *really* nasty workarounds). I'm not totally sure, though, so not answering...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For object monitors protected by `synchronized`, no, it either successfully locks or it blocks indefinitely waiting for a lock.

If you're using a `ReentrantLock` or the like, you have more options:

1. You can wait indefinitely, just like object monitors, by calling `lock`.
2. You can wait for a limited amount of time by calling `tryLock` with a timeout value.
3. You can immediately return if the lock is unavailable by calling `tryLock` with no arguments.

Comment: Hmm I know that it gets blocked and that i will have to wait for it to be unlocked,but my question is how do I Print something like **"This thread is waiting for the lock to be removed"** when another thread acceses a locked object.

Comment: Object monitors do not allow you to see which thread (if any) owns a lock. `ReentrantLock` does have a `getOwner` method you can call.

Comment: If you want to tell which threads are blocked, you can run `jstack`. This does not run inside of your Java program, though; it's an external process.

Comment: Thank You :) This worked ... although for some reason the `getOwner()` method is not showing up in eclipse,I used `tryLock` and it worked :) Although I dont know how my code works :P

Answer (score 1):

An inelegant workaround might look like the following:

```
// In the Workshop class.
private static final AtomicReference<Boolean> IN_USE = new AtomicReference<>(false);

private void getInLineToPunch(String name) {
  while(!IN_USE.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
    System.out.println(name + " is waiting in line to punch.");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(SOME_INTERVAL);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
      // This will probably not occur unless you interrupt this thread on purpose.
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  // At this point, no one is using the punch.
  System.out.println(name + " will now use the punch.");
  punch();

  // I am done with the punch.
  System.out.println(name + " is done with the punch.");
  IN_USE.set(false);
}
```

For this approach, it is necessary to use an `AtomicReference` to avoid race conditions.

Perhaps another approach is to use a monitoring thread to regularly poll each thread and announce that it is blocked.